# Mapeamento Code First com Data Annotations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

Estou a criar um projeto utilizando mapeamento através de `DataAnnotations` com *Code First* (semelhante ao *Hibernate*), sem o uso de `FluentAPI`.

Acontece que ao implementar este processo, algumas exceções estão sendo levantadas e acredito que seja devido a `DataAnnotations` que estou usando em lugares errados.

Então,

Qual é a função e utilização das `DataAnnotations` abaixo?

- `[ComplexType]`
- `[InverseProperty]`
- `[ForeignKey]`
- `[ScaffoldColumn]`

***Obs:*** *Estou tendo um problema com `ForeignKeys`, mas acredito que se entender bem as `DataAnnotations`, consigo resolver a `exception`.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### [`[ComplexType]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.complextypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Especifica que a classe em questão é um tipo complexo, utilizado para a contrução de vários outros *Models*.

Por exemplo:

```
[ComplexType]
public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    ...
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    ...
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

Um `ComplexType` normalmente não pode ser acessado diretamente por um contexto de dados.

### [`[InverseProperty]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.inversepropertyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Serve para indicar explicitamente uma relação N pra 1. É indicado quando o nome da propriedade não é padrão.

Por exemplo:

```
public class Movimentacao
{
    [Key]
    public int MovimentacaoId { get; set; }
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("UsuariosMovimentaramProdutos")]
    public virtual Produto Produto { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("UsuariosMovimentaramProdutos")]
    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
}

public class Usuario
{
    [Key]
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Movimentacao> UsuariosMovimentaramProdutos { get; set; }
}

public class Produto
{
    [Key]
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Movimentacao> UsuariosMovimentaramProdutos { get; set; }
}
```

### [`[ForeignKey]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Serve para indicar explicitamente qual a entidade estrangeira à qual a propriedade de chave estrangeira se refere. Por exemplo:

```
public class Usuario
{
    [Key]
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Movimentacao> UsuariosMovimentaramProdutos { get; set; }
}

public class Produto
{
    [Key]
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Usuario")]
    public OperadorDeCadastroId { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Movimentacao> Movimentacoes { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario OperadorDeCadastro { get; set; }
}
```

### [`[ScaffoldColumn]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.scaffoldcolumnattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Indica para o motor de *Scaffolding* se a coluna deve ser gerada ou não na sua *View*.

Normalmente é usado para **não** colocar a propriedade em *View*.